# Pull request shows replacement in file package json

Tags: git, package.json, pull-request

[image]
For some reason, in the package.json, code is replaced with exactly the same, although there were no changes in it.
What could be the reason ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953302/npm-package-json-formatted-in-one-line sorry for duplicate

Answer (score 0):

There's only a single line number there. Either the JSON was wrapped on a single line and it's being pretty-printed by the web interface, or the line endings (`\n` vs `\r` vs `\r\n`) was changed (and is not being picked up as new lines by the web interface).